# Need to change textcolor inside textarea with hiddenfield results

Tags: css, textarea, textcolor, hiddenfield

I have a form, which has a text area. I want to be able to set the text color of the text inside of the text area when they click the color intended.

So far, I have it to where when they click the color, it sets the hex color inside of a hiddenfield. How could I go about changing the textcolor with css based on the hiddenfield results.

I don't think I can alter the CSS with the GET/POST method, because I want the color to change immediately, not only when the form is posted. Is there a way to do this with either javascript or PHP?

I use the setting of the color to the hiddenfield using (through the img src):

onclick="document.getElementById('color').value = '#ffffff'; " />

HERE IS A JSFIDDLE OF WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:

jsfiddle.net/ymG6t

Comment: Can you post some code, please? A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is the preferred method.

Comment: I use the setting of the color to the hiddenfield using (through the img src):

onclick="document.getElementById('color').value = '#ffffff'; " />

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ymG6t/
(by the way, jsfiddle is pretty cool!)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out! Instead of using 
onclick="document.getElementById('color').value = '#ffffff'; " /> 
I used: onclick="document.getElementById('color').style.color = '#ffffff';" /> 
onto the field itself. No need for the hiddenfield!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. copy and paste code below:

```
<script>
function change_color(col){
    if ( col == 'red'){
        document.getElementById("text").style.color = '#f00'; 
    }
    if ( col == 'green'){
        document.getElementById("text").style.color = '#0f0'; 
    }
    if ( col == 'blue'){
        document.getElementById("text").style.color = '#00f'; 
    }

}

</script>

<form>
    <input type='radio' onchange="change_color(this.value)" name='color' value='red' >Red<br>
    <input type='radio' onchange="change_color(this.value)" name='color' value='green' >Green<br>
    <input type='radio' onchange="change_color(this.value)" name='color' value='blue' >Blue<br>

    Text:<textarea id='text'>Here is the text that you want to change it's color</textarea>
</form>
```

**Save into a new file with *.php extension.** 
If you want to save it as html, you must add html tag for header, body and other such as `<html>` in the beginning, `<head>`, and then `<body>`, and of course with it's close tag.
use it as a reference, you can modify the code/script as you need. 
 
may it help! :D